# Backbone JS Model diffrent API url

Tags: backbone.js

This is a newbie question for the backbone js

I would like to ask if it is possible to use diffrent API url on each model method

```
var login = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: apiUrl + 'member/login'
    initialize: function () {
        console.log('initialize')
    },
    logInEmail: function () {
        // will use urlRoot
    },
    validateEmail: function (emailToValidate) {
        // will use this url
        // apiUrl + 'member/validate'
    }
});
```

Comment: IMHO, modifying `urlRoot` for validation purposes is not a good way to achieve server-side validation. http://backbonejs.org/#Model-validate override it to make a ajax-call to the validate url.

Comment: Indirectly related, a good read - https://github.com/thedersen/backbone.validation

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.

Just change the `this.urlRoot`.
For your example it will looks like:

```
var login = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: 'member/login',
    otherApiUrl: 'othermember/login', 
    initialize: function () {
        console.log('initialize')
    },
    logInEmail: function () {
        // will use urlRoot
    },
    validateEmail: function (emailToValidate) {
        this.urlRoot = this.otherApiUrl; 
        // will use otherApiUrl
    } 
});
```

Be sure to set back the right `urlRoot` when you need it.

And yes, [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) issues should be observed.

**Edit**

Backbone includes [Backbone.sync](http://backbonejs.org/#Sync) which responsible for RESTful JSON interface.

`validateEmail` method could use simple $.ajax with `otherApi` url. Then it will return [promise](http://api.jquery.com/promise/) object, on which you could call your success function.

Other way to achieve this via Backbone, you should initialize `new Backbone.Model` to do the same task in Backbone way. I guess for your case $.ajax will be better choice.

Comment: how will i handle the return of each method? is it ideal to use jquery ajax inside model?

Comment: What you mean by "return of each method"? You can set urlRoot when initializing model. And you can use ajax call in model's methods. Could you fully describe your task/issue?

Comment: sorry i am a newbie in backbone js, i'm trying to research on how the other method will connect to API and how to handle the response data. for example: validateEmail will use otherApiUrl then how it will connect to API? does the backbone js have it's own way to connect to API or i will use something like jquery $.get() to connect to API? if backbone has it's own way then how i will handle the returns? sorry for the newbie questions... i really appreciate your response

Comment: I have updated answer. If you need more specific explanation please create [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with this issue and we will look at it.